# AWS Services variable names in boto3 method

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am trying to pass in AWS Services in a CostExplorer boto3 method but cannot get the names right. AWS seems to call their services by different names when it comes to passing them in as variables in boto methods. Is there a list of what their services are called when you need to pass them in as Boto variables? For example, to get a response from EC2 I need to write 'Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud - Compute', but for Lambda, I need to write 'AWS Lambda'. There seems to be no pattern.

For example, I get a response for all the services below except 'Amazon CodeBuild' and 'AWS Code Pipeline - Service'. It has been trial and error so far trying to get the names right, and have only found a few random examples in the docs.

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    ce = boto3.client('ce')

    response = ce.get_cost_and_usage(
        TimePeriod={
            'Start': last_week_string,
            'End': string_now
        },
        Granularity='MONTHLY',
        Filter={
            'Dimensions' : {
                'Key' : 'SERVICE',
                'Values' : ['Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud - Compute', 'Amazon Route 53', 'AWS Lambda', 'Amazon Virtual Private Cloud', 'Amazon ElastiCache', 'EC2 - Other', 'Amazon DynamoDB', 'Amazon CodeBuild', 'AWS Code Pipeline - Service']
            }
        },
        GroupBy=[{
            'Type': 'DIMENSION',
            'Key': 'SERVICE'
        }
        ],
        Metrics=['UnblendedCost']

    )
```

Comment: I think you could use [GetDimensionValues](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-cost-management/latest/APIReference/API_GetDimensionValues.html) to get the names?

Comment: Thank you Marcin. I did see that in the docs but it seems a little convoluted when all I need is a list of the services available, in the right format. I appreciate your answer though :)